# Backbone .remove() and .unbind() not killing zombies, creating more

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am creating a single page app using Backbone and functions are firing twice ("Show Answer" prints to the console twice, and the accordion slides down, then up).

```
events: {
    "click .question": "showAnswer"
},
showAnswer: function(e){
    console.log("Show Answer");
    $(e.target).siblings("div.hidden").slideToggle(600);
}
```

Through research I found out that this is most likely due to Backbone Zombies/memory leaks. I tried to implement the solutions suggested in [this LosTechies article](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/15/zombies-run-managing-page-transitions-in-backbone-apps/), other articles, and at least a dozen different Stack questions by adding .remove() and .unbind() whenever the view changed.

I'm using handlebars for templating, so I can't create a separate homeView and faqView and I have no models, making it difficult to implement the solutions offered.

The problem is, once I add .remove() and .unbind(), it causes the showAnswer() function to fire three times instead of two. For some reason, removing and unbinding the view is creating a third view.

Here is a fiddle with both my original code and the code with .remove()/.unbind added: http://jsfiddle.net/gR5aH/3/

Chances are very, very high that I'm calling the .remove/.unbind in the wrong place and the wrong way. I apologize for asking a question discussed a dozen times over, but I'm continuously failing to grasp the concept.

Any help would be immensely appreciated.

**EDITED:** updated the fiddle with html.

Comment: Can you add your html to the fiddle?

Comment: Updated fiddle in original post with HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Made minor additions to your code to get it working in a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/82n9L/2/

You'll want to note `undelegate()` on line 25:

```
this.$el.undelegate().fadeOut(1000, function(){
    self.render(app.current_page);
    self.$el.fadeIn(1500);
});
```

Since every time you instantiate a `UI` view, those events are being delegated on the `#main-container` element (Backbone uses `.delegate()` not `.bind()`). Each time you switch views back and forth, you re-delegate those events, resulting in the same handlers firing multiple times.

Also, line 37:

I changed:

```
var template = Handlebars.compile(source); // a function that accepts JSON
```

to:

```
var template = Handlebars.compile(source)(); // a compiled string
```

And finally, line 55:

```
//app.home();
```

You don't need to call `app.home()` explicitly. It gets triggered automatically when you start your router with `Backbone.history.start()`

Comment: THANK YOU! 
I did not know about delegate. I'll read up on it. Plus, great tip about the second set of parens on compile. 
You're a life-saver.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that you are calling the remove method first when you should be calling unbind first.  Also, you may want to use empty() instead (as it removes all event handlers of children and not just from the elem it's called on - not sure if it applies in this case though)

Comment: I've tried switching the order and using .empty() in the router function and the render. The former still makes the function fire three times and the latter unbinds all event listeners.

However, I will keep trying. Thank you!

Comment: Also, you might want to call those methods inside the actual views and not in the router (as that would avoid unbinding all event listeners).

Comment: A good practice for this is instantiating the view in an instance variable in the router, then defining a method in the view (dispose for example) that calls empty and unbind on the view's el.  Then when a new route occurs you can just call the view's dispose method via the instance variable in the router (you will have to add a check to make sure the view is not null though of course)